# Raise fps on android tablet above 60 for opengl \game

Tags: android, opengl-es, frame-rate

My question is: I have a android phone and tablet, both running android 4.0.
On the phone my game runs at 120 fps, on the tablet at 60. I understand the higher resolution may be a factor, but is 60 fps good for an android game? Anyway to achieve higher fps on the tablet?

I've tried using AndEngine and E3Droid for my game (As they are open gl 2.0 and 1.0/1.1 respectively) and yet both yield the same results.

Any tips? Maybe 60fps is more than enough for an android game? I am coming from XNA where i usually have well over 100 fps, hence my concern.

Comment: I think it is more than enough. Take advantage of any extra time you have and let your threads sleep for a little bit. Running any faster will just burn more power for a negligible benefit.

Comment: Consider that the [human eye/brain can only register about 12hz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate) .. (Such FPS appear "non smooth", but read the rest of the article ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of what is good for a game, this is totally out of your hands.  Rendering is capped at 60, or even 30 fps on many devices.  Don't worry about it, it is completely device dependent!

If you haven't already, look at implementing a fixed timestep in your game logic. [Here](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) is a great blog post on this subject.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think 60 fps is not bad I play lot of PC games and if you are getting too much fps it will start tearing image but when i use vertical sycronization frame rate drops to 60 FPS and no tearing will visible hence the phones and tablets use 60hz screen you should not worry about 60 FPS frame rate actually it may using vsync.

Answer (score 1):

60 frames per second should be more than enough! 30 frames per second is usually considered a normal and acceptable frame rate. 60 fps would probably yield better results, yet the higher you go, the less you'll actually notice any improvements.